# Ninject Intercept all instances of class X

Tags: aop, ninject, ninject-interception

I am trying out various frameworks implementations for AOP and I am really liking Ninject, however there is one criteria I just cannot get working for the life of me.

I am trying to get it to use an interceptor against all classes that are a typeof(X)... Here is my current code:

```
Kernel.Intercept(x => x.Binding.Target.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(X))).With<SomeInterceptor>();
```

I was originally trying x.Request.Blah opposed to x.Binding.Blah however neither way seemed to yield the results I was after... and the documentation for this amazing functionality is quite scarce and never seems to cover the Kernel.Intercept() extension...

Hopefully it is a simple answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.Binding.Target` is an enum that specifies the type of the provider. You have to look at `x.Binding.Service` which is the bound type. If you need the instantiated type you have to wait for the next release.

Comment: Bound type should be enough, will give it a whirl and post back if I am still unsure...